# Including hidden data in an HTML page for javascript to process

Tags: javascript, html, embed

I produce a complex HTML summary report from data in a database which could be a summary of maybe 200,000 rows in the database. The user can click a link to request an Excel version.

When they do a JS script extracts the key components of the report and stuffs them into a form in a hidden iframe. This form submits to a server-side script which generates the Excel version of the report (without the graphics etc).

As the calculations for the report are complex and "costly" it makes sense not to run them again to create the Excel version as all the data is on the page already. Also the user may have customised the report once it is loaded and I can use JS to pass those preferences to the form as well so the Excel doc reflects them too.

The way I am doing this is to include the following for each component of the report that transfers to a row in the Excel version. I've hijacked an HTML tag that isn't otherwise used.

```
   <code id="xl_row_211865_2_x" class="rowlabel">Musicals}{40%}{28.6%}{6</code>
```

The code element above is a summary of the row below in the HTML report which becomes one row in the Excel doc and includes the label and various data elements. There may be a thousand or more such elements in one report.

[image]

As the data contains text I've had to use something like `}{` as a field separator as this is unlikely to occur in any real text in the report. I have `code` set to display:none in the CSS.

When the user wants an Excel version of their report the JS code searches the HTML for any `<code>` elements and puts their className and innerHTML in the form. The className indicates how to format the row in Excel and the data is then put into adjacent cells on the Excel row.

[image]

The HTML report shows one percentage base (they can toggle between them) but the user preference when requesting an Excel version was to include both.

Is there a better way of doing this?

(As this is a part of a complex web app no user is going to turn CSS off or lack javascript or they wouldn't get this far)
ADDED: I can't use HTML5 as the users are corporates often on older browsers like IE6

Comment: How costly is this on the server (in actual terms).  Is it going to be significantly easier/more maintainable to do this on the server and not have several thousand potentially unused code tags in your initial load of the page?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but it seems that it could work for me: Keep a JSON object as a global variable? Or hidden somewhere? And when requesting, send the JSON to the excel parser?

Comment: Are the rows in the report in HTML or are they images? If they are HTML your javascript could just extract the info from it rather than storing it again in different extra tags.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the new data- attributes

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml

```
<div data-row="[[&quot;Musicals&quot;,40,28.6,6], ...]">
```

The div could be the `TD` tag or `TR` tag or any other relevant tag already related to the row and the `&quot;` is the escaped `"`.

That makes the data hidden from view and also ensures that there will come standard solutions to process the data.

Also for encoding data I would suggest using [JSON](http://www.json.org/) as that is also a standard that is easy to use.

Answer (score 13):

Standard solutions:

1) Use a Javascript data block:

```
<script>
var mydata = {
         'Musicals': ['6','40%','28.6%'],
         "That's Life": ['2','13.2%','0.5%'],
         ...etc....
      }
</script>
```

2) Use element attributes:
(see http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/ for more info)

```
<div class='my_data_row' data-name='Musicals' data-col1='6' data-col2='40%' data-col3='26.6%'>
```

...and then use Javascript to load the attributes as required.

This second option would be used when the data is related to the element in question. You wouldn't normally want to use this for data that's going to be used elsewhere; I would say that in your case, the simple Javascript data block would be a far better solution.

If you do go with the data attributes as per the second option, note the use of the 'data-' prefix on the attributes. This is an HTML5 specification that keeps user-defined attributes separate from normal HTML ones. See the linked page for more info on that.

Comment: #2 is out as these people often use old browsers.
#1 would be difficult as it stands as the data is generated as the report is built, so there would need to be inline JS code throughout the reports to add to an array or something and I'd rather avoid that

Comment: @derekcohen - attribute data does work in old browsers. Using the 'data-' prefix is merely a way to standardise a technique that people were using already.

Comment: @derekcohen - and re #1: what's the difference between inline JS code throughout your HTML and inline `<code>` elements throughout your HTML? A single line of JSON code in each block would not be a big overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the <del>new</del> html5 feature [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) instead of using hidden html fields, that is if you're sure that your users use <del>only latest</del> modern browsers.

Anyway, an improvement on your code would be to actually store the data in [`JSON`](http://json.org/) format:
Instead of

```
Musicals}{40%}{28.6%}{6
```

you would use something like

```
{
    "label": "Musicals",
    "percentage1": 40,
    "percentage2": 28.6,
    "otherLabel": 6
}
```

This way you can build javascript objects just by <del>evaluating (eval) or</del> parsing (`JSON.parse`) the innerHTML of the hidden element, in a faster way than you interpret your own curly brackets protocol.

Comment: our users are in big corporates, many of them still using IE6! So an HTML 5 solution is out I'm afraid

Comment: It's a good point, but what I find someway crazy is the fact of store 200k records in web browser, in any way. Local storage, data attributes or whichever solution. What amount of memory would take that in the client machine (local storage would be in the HDD, and data attributes in memory?).

Comment: @Matias It's stored in a file, but I believe the location and type of file is entirely up to the browser developer.  take a peak here : http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=68&t=118547

Answer (score 1):

My point to solve that in a better way would be take these results and save in some temporal XML file in the server, show the contents in the browser and when the user request for the Excel version, you only need to take the temporal XML.

Take a look to Linq-to-XML, because its fluent-style programming would help you in reading the XML file in few lines and then creating such Excel file.

Another solution would be serialize your object collection to JSON and deserialize them with the DataContractJsonSerializer. That would make the size of temp file smaller than XML approach.